# Add "Allow in the background" items from command line

Tags: applescript, command-line, cron, login-items

Some of the applications on my system run only if they are allowed to run in the background. I want to run these apps only in certain time windows.

Due to this, I am manually enabling the app in `System Settings` -> `Login items` -> `Allow in the background` and then once I am done with using the app, I am disabling it.

I want to write a cron job to automatically enable/disable items in the background.

Is there a way to do that from command line or osascript?